# In Yii, can I set my search result page headers dynamically to include the search phrase?

Tags: php, yii

I don’t even know how to write an example of this, sorry.

I want my search result pages to include the search term in the h1 on the page.
In my current site, I am able to simply echo the URL parameter in the page, but it’s a numerical value (like ‘1309’) that corresponds to a placeName in a joined table. The real ‘placeName’ appears in the GridView on the page, but I don’t know how to use that data outside the gridView.

Is there a way to do it?

In Yii2 gridView has a Caption property, which sounds like it would serve for this use, but I don’t think that property existed in Yii 1.

(And yes, still working on a Yii 1 site in 2023.)

Answer (score 1):

To include relational search keyword in view, provided that your search function is called from your CActiveRecord $model class:

1. Within your CActiveRecord $model class, define HAS_ONE relation to joined table as following:

   ```
   public function relations()
   {
       return array(
           'place_relation_name'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'place_table', 'place_id')
        );
   }
   ```
2. In your view now you should be able to access this relation as following:

   ```
   <?php echo $model->place_relation_name->placeName; ?>//Note, that in case no relation is found, $model->place_relation_name will returned as NULL;
   <h1>
       <?= $model->place_relation_name === null ? "-" : $model->place_relation_name->placeName ?>
   </h1>
   ```